# How can I write to my EKEventStore?

Tags: ios, calendar, swift2, ekevent, ekeventstore

I was saving my calendar events in the `defaultCalendarForNewEvents` before, it was working. Today it does not work any more but gives the error code: 6 "Calendar is read only".

The rights are requested properly before I try to modify the calendar. Why does it not work any more, and why was it working before with the same code?

*Note: I am using XCode's iPhone emulator to test this.*

***Code***:

```
func createEvent(eventStore: EKEventStore, title: String, startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) {
    let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)

    event.title = "Dodgy Codes"
    event.startDate = startDate
    event.endDate = endDate
    event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

    //Hardcoded testing data
    event.location = "Amsterdam"

    event.notes = "notes notes notes notes"
    do {
        try eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent)
    } catch let error as NSError {
    //error: Calendar is read only
    print("\(NSStringFromClass(CalendarController)): Adding event: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

**Output**:
[image: Output I get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems like this issue is solved, because it was not there in the first place. I confused myself with running it on the simulator, instead of real device. Trying to run the same code on iPhone6 worked. On the simulator it does not!
Advice for beginners: iOS simulator is not always reliable, after reaching some amount of complexity, it becomes really unreliable, especially with issues related to services like EKEventStore. Better test it always on the real devices, folks.

Comment: Not really a solution when sometimes it's preferable to use the emulator.

Comment: Down-voting colleagues is why I joined Stack-Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is issue with authorization , you need to take permission to access calender , try like this i hope it will work for you

```
func checkForEventAuthorization(eventStore: EKEventStore, completionHandler block:(granted: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void)  {
    if eventStore.respondsToSelector(Selector("requestAccessToEntityType:completion:")) == true {
        eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: { (granted, error) -> Void in
            block(granted: granted, error: error)
        })
    } else {
        block (granted: true, error: nil)
    }
}


    func createEvent(eventStore: EKEventStore, title: String, startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) {
    self.checkForEventAuthorization(eventStore, completionHandler: { (granted, error) -> Void in
        if granted == true {
            let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)

            event.title = "Dodgy Codes"
            event.startDate = startDate
            event.endDate = endDate
            event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

            //Hardcoded testing data
            event.location = "Amsterdam"

            event.notes = "notes notes notes notes"
            do {
                try eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                //error: Calendar is read only
                print("\(NSStringFromClass(CalendarController)): Adding event: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: sorry this doesn't work, I have requested the access properly before coming to this method here.

Comment: and I added this code snippet, to just check one more extra time if the access is granted, and I do get inside the granted block, but after that trying to save to the calendar, gives me the same error

Comment: then once check in iphone settings . either your app has permissions or not ,to access calender